# it is scroll search jquery, i wanted itemClass is fade slow speed show when i use window scroll

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted itemClass is fade slow sppeed when i am scroll... how use jquery scroll fade ............

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="items clearfix">
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
  </div>

  <div id="sample-data" style="display: none;" class="clearfix">
    <div class="pageSeparator" class="clearfix">Page Top</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/d3Dhn/1/

Comment: I don't understand, you want items to fadeOut relative to your scroll?

Comment: see my fiddle .. my frends ....  i wanted itemClass is show fade when i am window scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuddenDeath/kS9K7/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.item').each(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        var offset = $item.offset();
        var height = $item.height();
        if(offset.top<top && top<(offset.top+height)){
            var visible_persent = (offset.top+height-top)/height;
            $item.css({'opacity':visible_persent}); // todo: add support for all browsers
        }else{
            $item.css({'opacity':'none'});
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: hey myfreinds you answer is very good.. but i wanted items is scroll search. you answer is not scroll search.. also good.. how use fade item with scroll search...

Comment: can't understand what you mean by "scroll search"

Comment: may be you want to make lazy loading? like this one http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: yes that right.. your answer is greatwork, thank you very much

Comment: it will be even better if you will add elements line by line not all block 2x2, than it will look more smoothly

Answer (score 0):

you could use the jquery scroll event handler function

```
$(".items" ).scroll(function() {
```

$(this).fadeOut('slow');
});

Comment: please give me your fiddle